# вопрос по кроссплатформенной разработке

Tags: java, android

Есть ли инструменты, которые позволяют при написании игры для ОС android параллельно создавать экземпляр java игры, но для настольного ПК?

Comment: ваша игра как минимум будет доступна в эмуляторах андроида на пк. а вот без эмулятора тут врядли такое возможно если вы пишете именно под андроид

Comment: Дмитрий, про эмуляторы я знаю. Т.е., если не эмулятор - то никак, я правильно понимаю? Хотя странно, ведь андроид - это и есть java по своей сути.

Comment: нет андроид это ubuntu вообщето в первую очередь.  как операционная систеиа. а во вторых на настольных пк тоже разные Os установлены.

Comment: Версия для ОС Windows, если точнее. Я имела ввиду, что приложения для ОС Android пишутся на языке программирования Java

Comment: android - это операционная система, java - это язык программирования. Вы имели ввиду: "... ДЛЯ андроид НА java..."?

Comment: Небольшое и простое приложение можно написать на python и потом скомпилировать под Android.

Answer (score 5):

Самый простой вариант это движок Unity. Если знаком с C# или JavaScript, то особых проблем не будет.

Unity позволяет сразу компилить и под Windows, и под Linux и под Android. Разница будет лишь в том, что придется написать под комп и андроид разные классы управления, вот и все.

Answer (score 2):

В IDE "QT Creator" можно сделать такой фокус. Но только для самой примитивной программы типа "hello world". Во остальных случаях, как правило, в коде программы всегда приходится учитывать особенности конкретной целевой платформы. Хотя собрать для любой платформы (android, iOs, Windows Phone, MS-Windows, Linux) вы все сможете в одной IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Если знаком с JavaFx, можешь писать используюя [Gluon Framework](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/). Пишешь на JavaFx и при билде можно собирать в apk, ipa или же desktop. Один код - 3 платформы. И ко всему этому прикутить [OpenGL](http://opengl.j3d.org)

Answer (score 1):

LibGDX — фреймворк для создания игр и приложений, написанный на Java с использованием C и C++ (для более быстрой работы). Он позволяет писать кроссплатформенные игры и приложения используя один код.
Поддержка Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, Android ОС, Браузеры с поддержкой WebGL и iOS. 32 и 64-разрядные версии ОС;